# An extension that adds '#top' to the URL

Tags: google-chrome

Okay, so I've worked through trying to get this to work and I just have no clue; here is my manifest file:

EDIT: Now updated:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "To Top Button",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "Adds '#top' to the URL.",

  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "https://forums.robertsspaceindustries.com/*"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["adder.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "To the top!"
  }
}
```

EDIT: changed to a js file:

```
function updateUrl(tab){

   var currentURL = tab.url

   var newurl = currentURL.replace(currentURL + "#top");
   chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: newurl});
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {updateUrl(tab);});
```

Now, what I want to do, is when I click the icon, if I'm on a page that is sub to this (https://forums.robertsspaceindustries.com/) it adds "#top" to the end of the URL and then refreshes the page and takes me to the top.

What have I messed up?

Comment: You need to check if the URL is on your domain. Simple as that.

Comment: That hasn't helped, could you elaborate?

Comment: So when you say "messed up", what exactly is not working for you? Also what is the name of your html file and did you register it in the manifest?

Comment: `var newurl = currentURL.replace(currentURL + "#top");` pretty sure this is equivalent to `var newurl = currentURL + "#top";` (however both would not work if url already has a `#` in it).

Comment: The name is "adder.html" and by the looks of it I haven't registered it; I'm kinda new, how should I put it into the manifest file to make it run how I want it?

Comment: @Jacko I added an answer -- unfortunately do not have time to test that right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to move your script from HTML file to JS (according to [Manifest V2 Security Changes: Inline Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_migration_to_manifest_v2.html#inline_scripts)) and register it in the manifest.

If your JS is named `handler.js`, the manifest should be something like this:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "To Top Button",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "Adds '#top' to the URL.",

  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "https://forums.robertsspaceindustries.com/*"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["handler.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "To the top!"
  }
}
```

As for the code, try

```
function updateUrl(tab){   
   var newurl = tab.url.replace(/(#[^#]*)?$/, "#top");
   chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: newurl});
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) { updateUrl(tab); });
```

Comment: Thank you, this has fixed it :)

Comment: Okay maybe I was premature in saying that; although I think its my js file that's wrong, not your answer. The js file currently stands as `function updateUrl(tab){

    var currentURL = tab.url

    var newurl = currentURL.replace(currentURL + "#top");
    chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: newurl});
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {updateUrl(tab);});`

Comment: You can see it better in the OP

Comment: @Jacko I've updated the answer with some code. Let me know if it works,  but I would not be able to diagnose it without a specific error message/behavior (it is hard to diagnose without actually debugging in Chrome). If you need to identify the specific error, please refer to Chrome DevTools debugging information.

Comment: This works perfectly when there is nothing after the last "/", but sometimes there is something like "#Item_45" at the end of the URL (because it links to a specific post, usually happens when viewing the newest posts since last visit) is there a way to make sure the "/#top" is always the end rather than anything else?

Comment: @Jacko yes, I noted that answer was incomplete for existing `#`. I have updated the answer, please try it.